# How to get the src of next image to be loade din Nivo Slider

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I want to be able to get the src of the next image due to be loaded.  So I was thinking something like

```
 $('#nivo_slider').nivoSlider({

      beforeChange: function(){

           //get src of next image
    }
};
```

I can get the current image source by doing the following:

```
var currentImageSrc=$('#nivo_slider').data("nivo:vars").currentImage.attr('src');       
var index=currentImageSrc.lastIndexOf("/")+1;        
var imageName= currentImageSrc.substr(index);
```

But I'm not sure how to get the next one to be loaded

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="nivo_slider>
   <img src="img1" />
   <img src="img2" />
   <img src="img3" />
   <img src="img4" />

</div>
```

Comment: How to get the `src` of the next image depends entirely upon the current image, and its relationship to the next image. What's your HTML?

Comment: I've edited my question.  I can't do much about the html because I'm using nivo slider as a plugin for wordpress which integrates with another plugin that aloows the user to add images to a gallery.

Comment: Presumably the `currentImage` selector targets the current image? Or is there another selector to retrieve the current image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's part of nivo:vars that gives the current image. Not sure what else they contain, I could find a list anywhere.

Comment: Why would you need another selector when currentImage does it?

Comment: I don't, but I've not worked with the Nivo plugin before, so I was just checking that the `currentImage` selector did what I thought.

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking then I need to find out the index of the current image and add one to this to get the next image. I'm pretty sure nivo slider has a current slide which will return the index of the current slide. In which case I could add one to this and somehow using jquery get the next image source. Be useful if I could find out what nivo: vars actually holds. An array of images would be useful.

Comment: That's pretty much the only way I could find of achieving this, take a look at my answer and see if it helps. Incidentally, to see what's in `nivo:vars` just `console.log($('#nivo_slider').data('nivo:vars'));` and it'll be available in the JavaScript console for you to review. There is, sadly, nothing along the lines of a `nextImageToBeShown` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's one way to do it (and, despite some time spent trying there didn't seem to be an obviously-easier way):

```
/* Nivo seems to add images in order to implement its effects,
   so we need to grab a reference to the original images, or, at least, their `src` */

var images = $('#slider img').map(
    function() {
        return $(this).attr('src');
    });

$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    beforeChange: function() {
        var wrap = $('#slider'),
            // caching data because I'm accessing it twice:
            data = wrap.data('nivo:vars'),
            // the current src:
            current = data.currentImage.attr('src'),
            len = data.totalSlides,
            /* compares the current src against the srcs stored in the
               images variable, and returns the index at which it was
               found */
            arrayPos = $.inArray(current, images),
            nextSrc;

        if (arrayPos == (len - 1)) {
            /* if the array position of the src is equal to length-1
               (zero-based arrays in JS), then the next image to be
               shown will be the first in the array */
            nextSrc = images[0];
        }
        else {
            // otherwise get the next src from the next position in the array
            nextSrc = images[arrayPos + 1];
        }

        $('#output code.src').text(nextSrc);
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y6HhY/1/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: You're very welcome! Though I couldn't believe how difficult it was to implement. My conclusion? Nivo slider may well be the "world's most awesome jQuery & WordPress Image Slider" but it seems incoherently put together for finding next, and previous, images. Though I suspect such could be easily enough implemented into the plugin for the `nivo:vars` data object...

Comment: From that I guess it must've worked? And you're very welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: What if you click the prev link instead of next :(